# Diagnosing Account Kit (web) errors

Tags: account-kit

What's the best way to test against all the various exceptions one can get while going through the account kit phone number verification work flow? I'm seeing complaints from my users - some of which are tough to replicate. And since it's a live app, the error messages aren't highly descriptive either.